# 503 error on live environment ONLY when loading a laravel filemanager

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ckeditor

I am getting 503 errors when loading guillermomartinez/filemanager-laravel.

This is the url the browser is trying to load;

```
[my-web-root]filemanager/connectors?path=%2Ffilemanager%2Fuserfiles%2F&mode=getfolder&showThumbs=true&time=108 503
```

The symptom is a loading screen that will never finish loading:
[image: loading forever]

I must mention that on my local lamp server this is working without problems

Comment: A 503 error means the server is being overloaded.

Comment: Thanks Rory. Can you elaborate on this?